# Strongly-Typed ActionLink helper with Areas in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The strongly-typed action-link helpers in MvcContrib do not appear to work with areas:-

```
namespace MySite.Areas.Bar.Controllers
{
  public class FooController
  ...
```

and

```
<%: Html.ActionLink<FooController> %>
```

routes to /Foo, rather than /Bar/Foo

What other solutions are available for creating strongly-typed actionlinks that work with areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decorate your controller with the `[ActionLinkArea]` attribute to indicate that this controller is part of an area (yes there is no way for knowing this at runtime other than using reflection and looking if the containing namespace has Area in it which is not reliable. This behavior will change in ASP.NET MVC 4 where areas will be first class citizens of the framework):

```
[ActionLinkArea("Bar")]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now the following will generate proper link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<FooController>(x => x.Index(), "Go to index in Bar area") %>
```

Comment: What namespace is ActionLinkArea in? When I adorn my controller declaration with it, Visual Studio offers to generate the class for me, not reference it from somewhere.

Comment: Old question, but in case anyone ends up here, it's in the MVC Futures nuget package => https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/